# Can't map table to Symfony - Doctrine entity. The file was not found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to follow the official Symfony manual (just the name of table is different) and want to map my database table with the Entity. I created a class that is based on (copy/pasted the URL and file name, so typo is impossible):

> C:\xampp\htdocs\goodstuff\src\AppBundle\Entity\Customer.php

The source code of class file:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer")
 */
class Customer
{
        /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */ 
    protected $first_name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */     
    protected $last_name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */     
    protected $mid_name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */     
    protected $phone;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */     
    protected $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1000)
     */     
    protected $comments;

}
```

then I ran the command:

> c:\xampp\htdocs\goodstuff>....\php\php app\console
>   octrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Customer

or

> c:\xampp\htdocs\goodstuff>....\php\php app\console
>   octrine:generate:entities AppBundle\Entity\Customer

In both cases I am getting the same error message:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\goodstuff>..\..\php\php app\console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Customer

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer")
 */
class Customer
{
            /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
        protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
        protected $first_name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
        protected $last_name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
        protected $mid_name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
        protected $phone;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
        protected $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1000)
     */
        protected $comments;

}




  [RuntimeException]
  The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Entity\Customer" to be defined in file "C:\xampp\htdocs\goodstuff/src\AppBundle\Entity\Customer.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probab  ly has a typo.



doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with the missing error message?

Comment: @Veve I've modified it

Answer (score 3):

Try it with only your bundle name. Does it work then?

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

Or try it with the --path property, as the syntax states:

```
doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

Comment: 1) Bundle "AppBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.
2) with path it is saying "Not enough arguments."

Comment: What is the exact namespace of your entities? Is it really /src/AppBundle/Entity ?

Comment: Actually created entity, but not from existing class, but firstly I did generate:entity and after that generate:entities...

Comment: Did you tought about the fact that you don't HAVE to use the generate commands? You should be able to use the entities coded manually. I don't even trouble anymore about it.